# Is there a plugin for Firefox that forces Firefox to request the system password to view the passwords it stores?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, firefox, passwords

I left my computer open (didn't lock it), and it very likely that someone living with me went to see what passwords were there given that I am the one that told them how to do so. I wish Firefox were like Chrome.

Is there a plugin for Firefox that forces Firefox to request the system password to view the passwords it stores (just like in Chrome)?

Bloody Firefox!

Comment: What research on the web did you do before asking this question?

Answer (score 2):

No add-in is needed. In Firefox, select *Tools | Options*. On the *Security* tab, check *Use a master password. This can be set to anything -- the same as system login password, or any of your choice. Each time the dialog to view passwords is opened, the master password must be entered to view saved passwords.

[image]